# сортировка многомерного массива array_multisort() в цикле foreach()

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

код большой - показываю только не работающую часть

```
foreach ($tables as $val){

    $res_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE $sql_teams ORDER BY teams_name ASC ");
    $row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_1);
    $teams = array();do{$teams[] = $row_1;}while($row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_1));

    foreach ($teams as $key => $row) {
        $o[$key]    = $row['o'];
        $sh_z[$key] = $row['sh_z'];
        $sh_p[$key] = $row['sh_p'];
    }

    array_multisort($o, SORT_DESC, $sh_z, SORT_DESC, $sh_p, SORT_ASC, $teams);

}
```

получается что array_multisort() сортирует один и тот-же массив с разными значениями, если следующий массив больше предыдущего то проблем нет, а если меньше выскакивает ошибка Warning: array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

Comment: не могу себе представить, как массивы могут быть разного размера в вашем коде

Comment: @PavelSergeevich, так следующий массив сортируется опираясь на сортировку предыдущего и если он меньше, то отсутствуют элементы для сопоставления с предыдущим массивом. Отсюда ошибка. Или я чего-то не понял!?

Comment: а как сделать чтобы он не опирался на сортировку предыдущего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему, каждую итерацию $teams обновлялся а $o,  $sh_z, $sh_p - дописывались в созданный массив, добавляем unset() и всё работает:

```
foreach ($tables as $val){

    $res_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE $sql_teams ORDER BY teams_name ASC ");
    $row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_1);
    $teams = array();do{$teams[] = $row_1;}while($row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($res_1));

    unset($o);
    unset($sh_z);
    unset($sh_p);

    foreach ($teams as $key => $row) {
        $o[$key]    = $row['o'];
        $sh_z[$key] = $row['sh_z'];
        $sh_p[$key] = $row['sh_p'];
    }

    array_multisort($o, SORT_DESC, $sh_z, SORT_DESC, $sh_p, SORT_ASC, $teams);

}
```